# What does console input mean?

Tags: java, console

What does console input mean?Is it

```
Console co=System.console();
```

or

```
BufferedReader bufferRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```

or is it `String[]args`?

Comment: Reading input from the keyboard. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Console.html

Comment: Your BufferedReader line there is incredibly common (and correct). Just test something out and you'll see, bufferRead will basically contain whatever text you entered into the command-line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String[]args` are the command line arguments passed when calling the program, i.e.

```
java -jar myProgram.jar arg1 arg2 arg3
```

will store `arg1`, `arg2` and `arg3` in the `args` array.

---

```
Console co = System.console();
```

Will just assign the current console object to `co`.

---

The console input is the input taken from the keyboard, so in your case it is

```
BufferedReader bufferRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```

or, in a simpler way,

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Answer (score 2):

Extension of command line. It could be windows, linux or other OS standard console.

Where you could display program output or take input from console

Answer (score 1):

Methods to access the character-based **console device**, if any, associated with the current Java virtual machine.

So in this case, any input that we take from a character based console device; like keyboard.

Hope this helps.